# Saving metadata when converting music file in python

Tags: python, audio, metadata, converters, soundfile

I have the following Python script that should be able to convert a music file as an AIFF format. Everything works really well, however, the last function, `sf.write` do not allow me to save the new file with metadata.

```
import os
import soundfile as sf

# Specify the input and output directories
input_dir = r"C:\Users\lillo\Desktop\Music\try"
output_dir = r"C:\Users\lillo\Desktop\Music\try"

# Loop through all files in the input directory
for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".wav") or filename.endswith(".flac") or filename.endswith(".flac"):
        # Load the audio file and its metadata
        audio, sr = sf.read(os.path.join(input_dir, filename), always_2d=True)
        metadata = sf.info(os.path.join(input_dir, filename)).__dict__

        # Set the output filename and path
        output_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".aiff"
        output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_filename)

        # Write the AIFF file with the same metadata as the original file
        #sf.write(output_path, audio, sr, format="AIFF", subtype="PCM_16", endian="BIG", **metadata)
        sf.write(output_path, audio, sr, subtype="PCM_16", endian="BIG", format="AIFF")
```